# How to split whole page into two unequal size using minipage

Tags: minipage

I want to split the whole page into two parts. I am going to use left part as a sidebar.

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{cvGray}{rgb}{0.44, 0.52, 0.58}

\begin{document}    
\colorbox{cvGray} {
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}       
    \end{minipage}
}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\end{minipage}  
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Target output:

[image]

I generated the Target output with this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\definecolor{cvGray}{rgb}{0.44, 0.52, 0.58}

\begin{document}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
       \put(-20,-850){\color{cvGray}
       \rule{8cm}{81cm}}
    \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

I could have used the above code but it doesn't seem right way to do things. So how could I achieve the target output by using minipage ?

Answer (score 1):

Your boxes do not fit on one line, and you have a word space between them, so they are set one above the other.

---

*parindent*`\colorbox{cvGray} {`*fboxsep* *space*
`\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}`
*box content*
`\end{minipage}` *space*
*fboxsep*`}`*space*
`\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}`
*box content*
`\end{minipage}`

---

So, you need to remove the word spaces and account for the fboxsep padding added by `\colorbox`.

Also you need to force the boxes to be full height even when empty.

Something like this, depending a bit how tall you want the split in relation to page head and foot

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{cvGray}{rgb}{0.44, 0.52, 0.58}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\topskip}    
\noindent
\colorbox{cvGray} {%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-\baselineskip]{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
a
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-\baselineskip]{0.7\textwidth}
b
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I don't want page head and foot

Comment: ok add `\pagestyle{empty}` somewhere then @Ahtisham

Comment: where somewhere ? can you give hint

Comment: +1 for getting closer to the answer :)

Comment: actually more or less anywhere in this example. The line before `\begin{document}`  woudl be a good place

Comment: It does nothing.

Comment: @Ahtisham oh actually it does nothing _visible_ as the margin=0 setting you have used for geometry already pushes the page number off the page, (you may want to add a4paper unless you are using usletter paper)

Comment: setting `tmargin` to `-4mm` worked

Comment: How would I divide text into sections and have proper margin inside minipage ?

Comment: sorry I can't guess what you mean, better to ask as a new question with an example and showing the required output (as a sketch at least) @Ahtisham

Comment: why after including this `\usepackage[margin=0mm, a4paper,total={4in, 6in}]{geometry}` it still keeps little margin at top and bottom ? how would I fix it ?

Comment: I did this `\usepackage[a4paper,total={4in, 6in}, margin=0mm,tmargin=-1mm, bmargin=-2mm]{geometry}` and it got fixed. Do you know any better solution ? After this I think now I would need to add box inside of each minipage which will have its own margin and inside of it I can write text.